# How to limit the user input?

Tags: c

I'm new to programming and I want to know how to check if the user input is within my condition. For example, the program only accepts inputs which are below 25.

Here is my code. But it isn't working. :(

```
for(i=1; i<=5; i++);
{
   if(act[i]<25)
   {
      scanf("%d", &act[i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not working because you are trying to evaluate the if condition `if(act[i]<25)`  before `act[i]` is actually received from the user.

What you need is this:

```
for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
    again:
    scanf("%d",&act[i]);
    if(!(act[i]<25))
    {
        printf("Invalid input! Enter again..\n");
        goto again:
    }
}
```

the if condition has to be after you have scanned act[i]. 
If the user enters a number that is not within the desired range then a message is printed and you have to enter the number again.

Also, there shouldn't be a semicolon after `for(i=1;i<=5;i++)`

Comment: People who learned to program after 1980 would probably do this without a goto.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you want to try forever if you keep receiving numbers grater than or equal to 25.

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
   int n;
   do{
     scanf("%d", &n);
   } while(n>=25);
   act[i]=n;
}
```